# iOS 8 Today Widget - SLComposeViewController not displaying properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension, today-extension

I've created an extension, in fact a Today Widget, using Xcode 6 and run it on my iOS 8 beta device (I am a registered iOS developer).

However, being new to development, I've encountered this issue with the `SLComposeViewController` being 'stuck' inside its view (shown below), deeming the user to be unable to interact with it and not be able to consequently post a tweet.

[image: Image for reference:]

Is there any way to fix this and bring the `SLComposeViewController` to the front, in front of the Notification Centre pane? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** (yay, fixed that "Hello World" text)

**2nd Edit:** Here's my `SLComposeViewController` code:

```
- (IBAction)TwitterShare:(id)sender; {

    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                               composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else

    {

        UIAlertView *twitterAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh!" message:@"Ensure you have setup a valid Twitter account and/or you have allowed access for Twitter in this application." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


        [twitterAlert show];
        twitterAlert = nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your SLComposeViewController code?

Comment: Shared as above, any help would be great!

Comment: FYI IIRC you can't use the keyboard from a Today extension. Let me try and find the reference on that.

Comment: Found it. From the [App Extensions Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1): "Because user interaction with widgets is quick and limited, you should design a simple, streamlined UI that highlights the information users are interested in. In general, it’s a good idea to limit the number of interactive items in a widget. In particular, **note that iOS widgets don’t support keyboard entry.**"

Comment: Looks like you really need to [adjust the height](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24042262/2446155)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's documentation SLComposeViewController is not allowed to be shown in NC. They want anything that requires keyboard entry to happen in-app.